# Open new file in new frame without raising existing frames (Windows)

Tags: frames, emacsclient

I run Emacs in a MSWindows environment (via server launched with `runemacs`), and open new files with `emacsclientw.exe -n [filename]`. It works very well, except for a detail in the second case below:

1. If the file to open already exists in a buffer, then Emacs raises the frame of that buffer, if such frame exists, otherwise it creates a new frame and displays that buffer. This is excellent.
2. If the file to open does not already exist in a buffer, then Emacs **first raises an existing frame**, and then creates a **new** frame & buffer and displays the file in this new frame/buffer. This is OK except that the first frame raised often gets in the way of other open windows, so I must minimize it again.

Is there a way to make Emacs always behave as in case 1 above also for files that don't yet have a buffer? In other words, I'd like Emacs to display the new file in a new frame & buffer, without first raising any existing frames.

I've tried changing the options `Pop Up Frames` (which in my case had value `never`) and `Pop Up Windows` (original value `non-nil`) in various combinations of values, but they don't seem to help.

Comment: I don't have this behavior.  If I use emacsclient <existingfile>, then the already existing Frame is used to open a new buffer with this file.  If the Frame does not have that buffer, it is is opened. If no Frame (with or without a buffer of <existingfile>) then I must use 'emacsclient -c' to create a new frame.  Same behavior when doing with <non-existingfile>.